# Primefaces Theme behind reverse tls proxy does not apply

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces, themes, reverse-proxy

I have an Spring Boot JSF / Joinfaces 4.3 / Primefaces 8 with Theme "omega".It is packaged as a war with maven using spring-boot-maven-plugin.

The theme applies well when running on my localhost. (see picture below)

But when I deploy the war on the VM that is behind a reverse proxy (that performs the TLS for facing browsers and the port mapping and maybe some firewall rules) the theme does not apply.

What is weird is that I don't have any HTTP error code when sniffing the network (dev tools in the browser).

My setting in application.properties and pom.xml is as below.
I don't get what is wrong and how the themes are applied and where to find a hint in the code

```
server.port=9092 
server.servlet.context-path=/rulesengine/prescription/gui
server.use-forward-headers=true
#
# jsf
#
joinfaces.primefaces.font-awesome=true
joinfaces.primefaces.theme=omega


-----------------
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
          <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

on my localhost

[image]

Behind the reverse proxy

[image]

Comment: I noticed as well that behind the reverse proxy, the following statement in the xhtml fails <h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.12.0/css/all.min-jsf.css" />. ( the dependency in the pom for font-awesome is present). whereas it works on my localhost ( no reverse proxy).

Comment: I found very old stuffs about that but I wonder if it is still relevant after this time https://ahoehma.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/jsf-behind-reverse-proxy/

Comment: in JoinFaces are you using Undertow, Tomcat, or Jetty as your Servlet engine?  Depending on which one there may be some config for reverse proxy?

Comment: As I use plain spring boot and inside it joinfaces, this is tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

No need to include anymore the webjar for font-awesome as they are now included by default.
So by removing <h:outputStylesheet>, even if I didn't solve the proxy difference, I don't have this error anymore and I get the icons.
For the theme, this was my fault. bad configuration.  with the 2 stuffs below everything works fine now.

> joinfaces.primefaces.font-awesome=true

> joinfaces.primefaces.theme=omega

Comment: Sure you have this answer on the right question? Does it solve this problem? Or is it purely related to the webjars thing? For which I would suggest to keep using the external since it is easier to update) PrimeFaces dropped providing it in 'favour' of using the external one

Comment: See https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/fonticons